# what is the meaning of "after Angular first displays the data-bound properties"

Tags: javascript, angular, methodology, angular-lifecycle-hooks, angular2-databinding

I'm following the Angular documentation about the `ngOnInit` lifecycle until it gets really confused by saying "after Angular first displays the data-bound properties". Btw, you can check the documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence). I guess the meaning of the word `display` in the context of the whole sentence is `render` but it doesn't make any sense.

I put a `debugger` statement to the `ngOnInit` method of a component to see what will be displayed/rendered at the time the method is called, but nothing is rendered, including DOM elements having data-bound properties except the ones that don't have any data-bound properties.

So what does it mean according to the documentation by saying "after Angular first displays the data-bound properties"?

Comment: The use of the word "display" is simply incorrect. It cannot be reimagined as "rendered" either as that would be equally wrong. The term used should be "set" as in "after Angular first sets the data-bound properties". The "setting" of a data-bound property creates an internal side-effect that is used internally to mutate the DOM element property associated with the binding. All of this happens prior to the rendering of any data-bound elements. You should submit a documentation bug and ask the team to change the term. (good luck with that.).

Comment: it makes a lot of sense to me now, thank you. I will submit the Angular team the documentation bug which takes me so much time to get right